# How to attach files to input tag of type file by code

Tags: html, dom, browser

Is it possible to attach a file (located in the user's PC) to an `input[type=file]` element by code?

I use VB6 right now to do this (or at least I try) but any language would do.

(EDIT: I use a WebBrowser control.)

Comment: How are you connecting the HTML document to the VB program? Some kind of embedded Internet Explorer COM control?

Comment: Yes. I use a WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is You **can't**

You can only make the user click the input button and then make him choose the files.

Even if you find a workaround for doing it from code(*Which is quite impossible for me*),

The browsers will never allow you to bypass their security measures.

Even if it is supported today, most browsers are intelligent and learning day by day.

They sure will unsupport it in the very near future

So there's no chance of achieving what you want.

Comment: It seems that's the case. Finally, I have decided to make the post myself by retrieving the form values and putting them in my request.